# API running indefinitely

Tags: ajax, api, postman

I need help to figure out how to debug my problem.

I've got an ajax request being sent to my `site.com/api/test?stuff` with the correct headers in the `beforeSend()` and everything. But I get NO results back, no information back, when I run it in Postman I just get an infinite loading lasting forever with no errors returned. I don't know where to start looking for answers.

It does work locally and in my development area, but in production it does not. So that means the API in itself should be working, but I can't understand why does it give me an infinite loop when I try to access it in prod.

How can I debug this request ?

Comment: You need to provide more information... Starting with... Server? Environment? Backend language?

Comment: @DarrenSweeney The backend language is in PHP, in a unix environment, and I'm using swagger PHP. Define "server" in this context?

Comment: Server meaning are you using Node and Express? Apache?

Comment: @DarrenSweeney ooh, apache

Comment: Ok, so no node server or anything that involves ports? I've seen this a lot if proxies and reverse proxies aren't set up correctly